# add_command discord.py not working "The command passed must be a subclass of Command"

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror

I am currently updating my discord bot and wanted to add new functionality which allows me to add and remove commands through discord, without having to modify the code directly.

I found out that there are already existing methods (namely "Bot.add_command" and "Bot.remove_command" which do exactly what I want.

The "remove_command" part works perfectly, but I'm having trouble adding back the command using the add_command function. I've read the documentation but I don't seem to understand what's causing my error (outlined below).

Code:

```
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def removecommand(ctx, command):
        try:
            client.remove_command(command)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err) 
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
    
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def addcommand(ctx, command):
        command = client.get_command(command)
        await client.add_command(command)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: The command passed must be a subclass of Command`

Could someone please help me? I don't seem to understand what this means. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/discord mj market/1 mainmarketplace.py", line 121, in addcommand
    await client.add_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1132, in add_command
    raise TypeError('The command passed must be a subclass of Command')
TypeError: The command passed must be a subclass of Command

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: The command passed must be a subclass of Command
```

Comment: Can you include the _full_ error traceback? This will make it easier to diagnose the problem, since `CommandInvokeError` is a very general exception.

Comment: @JacobLee done, apologies for that. "The command passed must be a subclass of Command" its this part which has me confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discord.utils.find(lambda cmd: str(cmd) == "yourcmdname", client.commands)`

This will find your bot's command if exists else returns `None`. Also if you will use that removed command again, you can disable it.

```
@client.command()
async def toggle(ctx, cmd):
    command = discord.utils.find(lambda c: str(c) == cmd, client.commands)
    if command:
        command.enabled = not command.enabled
        if command.enabled:
            await ctx.send(f"{cmd} enabled.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{cmd} disabled.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Command not found")
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what I needed! It works perfectly. However, I would like to understand this if possible.

Comment: command = discord.utils.find(lambda c: str(c) == cmd, client.commands)
and         command.enabled = not command.enabled

could you please explain the purpose of these 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

The argument `command` passed to `add_command` or `remove_command` must be a [`discord.ext.commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Command) object. When members of your guild call the command, they will be passing strings to the argument (hence the error message).

There are two ways to get the `Command` object corresponding to a command name:

1. (Recommended) Using the [`Bot.get_command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_command) method. This will return the `Command` object corresponding to a command name (or alias) or `None`, if the command cannot be found. *Note: Command names are case-sensitive*.
2. Using the [`Bot.walk_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.walk_commands) method. This will return a generator yielding each `Command` object connected to the `Bot` object.

As for the `add_command()` method, the argument must also be a `Command` object. Thus, you would have to create your own `Command` object (which requires a function `func` and a name `name`, among other things). It would be best to have the functions already defined as `Command` objects (using the `Bot.command()` decorator). If that is the case, then the above two methods will work as well.

---

### Bot.get_command()

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def removecommand(ctx, command):
    cmd = client.get_command(command)
    if cmd is None:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Command `{command}` does not exist")
    client.remove_command(cmd)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

---

### Bot.walk_commands()

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def removecommand(ctx, command):
    for cmd in client.walk_commands():
        if cmd.name.lower() == command.lower():
            client.remove_command(cmd)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
            return
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Command `{command}` does not exist")
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much. However, I just realised why my "addcommand" command isn't working. Lets say I have a list of 2 commands:
command 1: ping
command 2: pong
when i use remove_command on command 1, the command is removed from the command list, as expected.
however, when trying to use the add_command, the bot is not able to detect the command and when I use .get_command(), it returns None.

Comment: Basically, what i want to do is temporarily disable a command and add it back when I need it. What would be the best way to do this?